# Why does my ActionListener will not work?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am creating a simple app that codify a text but i am struggling with some ActionListeners. When I'm choosing something from JComboBox there must happen things (if you choose Caesar's Cipher, an offset must appear, if you choose Beaufort, the offset will dissapper; the offset is a JTextField) and according to the choose the execute button will get the according ActionListener implementation. The thing is, When I'm choosing the Caesar's Cipher nothing happens, even if i add CaesarsCipher that implements ActionListener to codify the text, nothing will work.

MyFrame.java

```
package cipher;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JButton executeButton;
    private ComboBoxPanel leftPanel;
    private TextPanel rightPanel;

    public MyFrame(String title) {

        super(title);

        //Initiate the frame
        initFrame();
        //Initiate the button that need to be pressed to execute a cipher
        initButton();

        //Init the panels
        initPanel();

        //Pack everything together;
        packing();

        //Make the frame visible to the user
        setVisible(true);
    }

    //////////PACKING EVERYTHING TOGETHER//////////

    private void packing() {

        add(executeButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    }

    //////////INITIATING THE FRAME WITH ALL COMPONENTS//////////

    private void initPanel() {

        leftPanel = new ComboBoxPanel();
        rightPanel = new TextPanel();

    }

    private void initButton() {

        executeButton = new JButton("Execute cipher");

    }


    private void initFrame() {

        setSize(800,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setResizable(false);

    }

    //////////HIDE THE OFFSET WHEN CHOOSING ALGORITHMS THAT DO NOT REQUIRE OFFSET//////////

    public void hideOffset() {
        leftPanel.hideOffset();
    }

    public void showOffset() {
        leftPanel.showOffset();
    }


    //////////UPDATE LEFT PANEL AFTER HIDING OFFSET//////////
    public void updateLeftPanel() {
        leftPanel.updatePanel();
    }

    //////////LISTENERS//////////

    /////COMBO BOX/////

    public void addComboBoxListener(ActionListener comboBoxListener) {
        leftPanel.addComboBoxListener(comboBoxListener);
    }

    /////EXECUTE BUTTON/////

    public void addExecuteButtonListener(ActionListener executeButtonListener) {
        executeButton.addActionListener(executeButtonListener);
    }

    //////////GETTERS//////////

    /////OFFSET GETTER/////
    public Integer getOffset() {
        return Integer.parseInt(leftPanel.getOffset());
    }

    /////INPUT GETTER/////

    public String getInputText() {
        return rightPanel.getInputText();
    }


    //////////SETTERS//////////

    /////OUTPUT TEXT SETTER/////
    public void setOutputText(String text) {
        rightPanel.setOutputText(text);
    }

}
```

ComboBoxPanel.java

```
package cipher;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ComboBoxPanel extends JPanel {

    private final String []CIPHERS = {"Caesar's Cipher", "ROT13", "Beaufort Cipher", "Autokey Cipher"};
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private JComboBox comboCiphers;

    private JTextField offset;

    public ComboBoxPanel() {

        initSize();
        initComboBox();
        initBorder();
        initLayout();
        initTextField();

        packing();

    }


    private void initTextField() {

        offset = new JTextField(10);

    }

    private void initLayout() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    }

    private void packing() {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.ipadx = 10;
        add(comboCiphers,gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(offset,gbc);

    }

    private void initBorder() {

        Border outer = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Border inner = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose the cipher");
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outer, inner));

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    private void initComboBox() {

        comboCiphers = new JComboBox(CIPHERS);

    }

    //Remainder: delete this, let the layout to do its job.
    private void initSize() {
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 390;
        setPreferredSize(size);

    }

    public void hideOffset() {
        offset.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void showOffset() {
        offset.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void updatePanel() {
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    public void addComboBoxListener(ActionListener comboBoxListener) {
        comboCiphers.addActionListener(comboBoxListener);
    }

    public String getOffset() {
        return offset.toString();
    }

}
```

TextPanel.java

```
package cipher;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TextPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTextArea inputArea, outputArea;
    private JScrollPane inputScroll, outputScroll;

    public TextPanel() {

        //////////PANEL METHODS///////

        /*
        //Initiate the size of the panel
        initSize();
        */

        //Initiate the border of the entire panel
        initBorder();
        //Setup the layout of the panel
        initLayout();

        //////////TEXT AREAS METHODS///////
        //Initiate the text areas
        initTextArea();
        //Initiate the borders for the 2 text areas
        initTextAreaBorder();
        //Create scrolls for both text areas
        initScrollPane();

        //Pack everything together
        packing();

    }

    private void packing() {

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(inputScroll,gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        add(outputScroll,gbc);

    }

    private void initScrollPane() {

        inputScroll = new JScrollPane(inputArea);
        outputScroll = new JScrollPane(outputArea);

    }

    private void initTextAreaBorder() {

        inputArea.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        outputArea.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));

    }

    private void initBorder() {

        Border outer = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Border inner = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Text");
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outer,inner));

    }

    private void initLayout() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    }

    private void initTextArea() {
        inputArea = new JTextArea(10,77);

        outputArea = new JTextArea(10,77);
        outputArea.append("Output...");
        outputArea.setEditable(false);

    }

    public void addComboBoxListener(ActionListener comboBoxListener) {
        //.addActionListener(comboBoxListener);
    }

    /*private void initSize() {

        //setPreferredSize sets the minimum
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 390;
        setPreferredSize(size);

    }*/

    public String getInputText() {
        return inputArea.toString();
    }

    public void setOutputText(String text) {
        outputArea.append(text);
    }

}
```

ApplicationController.java

```
package cipher;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class ApplicationController{

    private MyFrame frame;

    public ApplicationController(MyFrame frame) {

        this.frame = frame;
        this.frame.addComboBoxListener(new ComboBoxListener());

    }

     class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener {

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JComboBox c = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
                String selected = c.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if(selected.equalsIgnoreCase("Caesar's Cipher")) {
                    frame.addExecuteButtonListener(new CaesarsCipher());
                    frame.showOffset();
                    frame.updateLeftPanel();
                } else if(selected.equalsIgnoreCase("ROT13")) {
                    frame.showOffset();
                    frame.updateLeftPanel();
                } else if(selected.equalsIgnoreCase("Beaufort Cipher")) {
                    frame.hideOffset();
                    frame.updateLeftPanel();
                } else if(selected.equalsIgnoreCase("Autokey Cipher")) {
                    frame.hideOffset();
                    frame.updateLeftPanel();
                }

            }

        }

     class CaesarsCipher implements ActionListener {

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             int offset = frame.getOffset();
             char []text = frame.getInputText().toCharArray();

             for(int i = 0 ; i < text.length ; i++) {
                 text[i] = (char)(((int)text[i] + offset) % 26);
             }

             String newText = new String(text);
             frame.setOutputText(newText);

         }

     }

}
```

Please someone explain what is wrong. I am ready to learn from mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't create an instance of your applicationController so your comboBox Listener was never created.

In the future, you should not be extending JFrame.  All you need is an instance of it.  You have also added complexity by putting in those extra add listener methods.

Comment: This works now but I've run into a problem where my button won't do its job.